# Arrow not shown in jsplumb connection

Tags: javascript, jsplumb

I have created a connection between to div block using jsplumb. I want to add arrow on top of the connection line. Now the arrow is not shown up. I have no idea on it.

Is there any idea why the arrow does not show up? Any thing missing?  Thanks a lot.

`
HTML:
**ABC**
**XYZ**

CSS:

## window20 {TOP: 10em; LEFT: 10em; WIDTH: 8em;}

## window21 {TOP: 26em; LEFT: 10em; WIDTH: 8em;}

Javascript:
jsPlumb.connect({
                source:"window20", 
                target:"window21", 
                anchors:["Bottom", "Top"], 
                connector:"Straight", 
                endpointsOnTop:true,
                overlays:["Arrow"]
            });

`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
jsPlumb.bind('connection', function (e) {
        jsPlumb.select(e).addOverlay(["Arrow", { foldback: 0.2, location: 0.65, width: 25 }]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Its working code currently m working with. All the best :-)
`jsPlumb.bind("jsPlumbConnection", function(e) {
                jsPlumb.select(e).addOverlay([ "Arrow", { foldback:0.2, location:0.75, width:25 } ]);
        });`

Comment: What is object "jsPlumbConnection"? Thanks.

Comment: You can say that this will actually return you every newly form connection object. So in callback you can work on that object. :-)